# A problem about generating [] automatically

Tags: front-end, keyboard

I have using the Wolfram Mathematica for two years. And I know the Mathematica has the operation <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> that can generate `[]`.
However, when I use this shortcut,it cannot generate a `[]`.

So my question is:

1.How to generate the `[]` rightly?

2.In other IDE like `InteljIDEA`, when I key the symbol `[`, it will generate the `[]` automatically.

Is it possible to do that in `MMA front-end`?

[image]

### Edit

As  @xzczd said,the <kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>)</kbd> will generate

[image]

In addition, it is not convenient to use the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>)</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>}</kbd> because I must key three keyboard <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>

Comment: With regards to point 1, you need to type `Alt + ]` to generate the `[]`. You're typing the wrong bracket.

Comment: @blochwave According to the rest part of OP's question, I think it's a typo and correct it. As to OP's first question, what's your input method editor (IME)? In fact I just found my IME for Chinese character input will break this shortcut and after I turned it off, the shortcut works well.

Comment: Well, my last comment is only to the first question i.e. the generation of `[]`, when you thought you pressed `Alt + )` you actually pressed `Alt + 0`, which is another shortcut (that seems to be changed in v10? I'm still in v9 anyway.) And just as what you've noticed, to generate `{}` and `()` one needs to press 3 keys, which I personally don't feel it convenient, either.

Comment: Not an answer to the original question, but you can change keybindings as described [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3575/emacs-key-bind-on-mathematica-linux/3576#3576)

Answer (score 4):

Auto-completion of brackets has been introduced in version 13:

https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2021/12/launching-version-13-0-of-wolfram-language-mathematica/

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/EnterPairedDelimiters.html