# Custom (emacs) key bindings for open/save in Mathematica 11

Tags: keyboard, linux

Is it possible to change the key bindings for Open and Save?

This used to be possible in MenuSetup.tr, along the lines of [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3575).  In Mathematica 9, there were explicit "Open" and "Save" (and "SaveRename") commands, with explicit bindings that could be changed.  These entries have now been replaced by "MenuListOpenItems" and "MenuListSaveItems", each of which adds multiple items to the menu.  But I haven't found a way to customize those items -- and the old "Open" and "Save" commands no longer seem to work.

I would be happy with either:

1. Information about how to change the key bindings associated with the entries in these submenus; or
2. A replacement for the "Open", "Save", and "SaveRename" commands so I can add my own keybindings directly to MenuSetup.tr.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.  I'm running Mathematica (9.0 and) 11.3 under Ubuntu 18.4.